# What is the memcpy equivalent in C++

Tags: c++

What would be the equivalent of using memcpy to a buffer, or string in C++?

For example:

```
char message_buffer[32];
uint16_t n = 457u;
memcpy(message_buffer, &n, sizeof(n));
...
```

Something like:

```
std::string message_buffer;
uint16_t n = 457u;
std::copy(messagebuffer, n);
```

Is there no C++ equivalent? Do I just stick to using memcpy, but instead with std::string?

```
std::string message_buffer;
message_buffer.resize(32);
uint16_t n = 457u;
memcpy(&message_buffer[0], &n, sizeof(n));
```

I guess I should give more background on what I am trying to do - simply I am sending and receiving data using sockets. The data needs to be pre-appended with the 16 bit binary representation of that number (457). So the examples I gave are but the first step, afterwards I copy the information I would like to send to the buffer, knowing that the first 2 bytes (16bits) contain the "magic number" binary.

Comment: Maybe you really want [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)?

Comment: Do NOT use memcpy on std::string and other classes. I wanted to write you an example but I don't understand what you are doing. Is your real question how to pack a 16-bit integer value in an array of bytes?

Comment: The equivalent are (copy-) constructors. If you are doing type-unsafe byte movement outside of the container, it's probably not C++ design in first place and you are trying to write C code with fancy trendy things from `std` namespace. There is not enough of the (high-level) context in the question to propose any C++-ish solution. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: What value do you expect in the first and second byte? You can't assume `memcpy` will put `01010111` in the first byte.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An `std::string` is for strings. If you want a buffer of bytes, you should use `std::vector<char>` (or its signed/unsigned counterparts) or `std::array` for small fixed length buffers instead.

Using `std::copy` is pretty much always the way to go, especially while in the "high level C++ realm" with all its classes etc.

However, I would say when you are dealing with low level constructs like byte buffers, the C++ function `std::memcpy` is the most appropriate choice. Just remember, `std::memcpy` is a "dumb" function that only copies bytes, but considering that we are trying to fill a byte buffer, that is what we want.

```
std::array<char, 32> buffer;
uint16_t n = 457u;
std::memcpy(buffer.data(), &n, sizeof(n));
```

Of course, if you want to store a more complex class with e.g. pointer members or non-trivial copy constructors (anything that is not "plain old data") in some byte buffer, you would need to serialize the object to get meaningful results, just as you would in C for structs with pointer members.

Analogously, you cannot simply use `memcpy` to get the data from the buffer back into some complex type. You would have do de-serialize the raw byte data in an appropriate way.

Comment: How is it most appropriate? The result depends on the implementation due to endianness. You might as well use `std::copy` with a `reinterpret_cast`. At  least it will stand out in the code as potentially dangerous.

Comment: @NeilKirk *"At least it will stand out in the code as potentially dangerous."* As will `std::memcpy`. vOv You want to copy some bytes somewhere, and that is what `std::memcpy` does and is there for.

Comment: You could also use `memcpy` to copy an array of the same basic type from one place to another, which is not dangerous. This can happen if you inherit legacy C code.

Comment: @NeilKirk One should not do this in new code (as I wrote above, as long you as you stay in the normal C++ type system, use `std::copy`), but yes, one might find it in legacy code. Is your point that it is only part of the language for legacy reasons and should not be used at all? If so, I would disagree. If you are going to copy bytes (which I usually don't) `std::memcpy` is fine by my standard.

Comment: My advice is never to use `std::memcpy` for any purpose. If you want to copy bytes, use `std::copy`. If you want to copy bytes in an implementation-specific way, use `std::copy` and the appropriate cast to warn others.

Comment: For me, both `memcpy` and `reinterpret_cast` imply a warning for all readers. In the end, I find `reinterpret_cast` more dubious and harder to read than `memcpy`, maybe because I do not even know what I can `reinterpret_cast` to what by heart. But I guess we are getting into opinion based terrain here.

Comment: There are many hidden gotchas in the C++ standard template library, and it differs per platform. I suggest sticking to as many C APIs as possible. They're the most reliable we have as they're the oldest we have in the C family.

Answer (score 3):

For the specific task you're doing, copying the byte representation of an object of some unrelated type into a buffer, `memcpy` is the appropriate function. This is specifically because it's one of the few legal ways to do this sort of thing independent of the types involved. Of course its use is limited as it's only valid with trivially copiable types.

When you're copying something where you don't want to destroy static type information, C++ provides other methods, such as the `std::copy` algorithm which operates on iterators rather than just `void*` as `memcpy()` does.

Answer (score 0):

To encode the 16-bit number 457 into a byte array such that the first byte is `01010111` and the second byte is `00000100` in a platform-independent way, use:

```
unsigned char buffer[2];
const uint16_t n = 457u;
buffer[0] = n & 0xFF;
buffer[1] = (n >> 8) & 0xFF;
```

You can wrap this logic in a function if you need to do it often.

You cannot assume `memcpy` will have the same affect. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Could you explain why/how this works? Also, this seems a lot less portable than using memcpy. With memcpy you could copy a lot of different primitive types.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera You need to research bitwise operations. Portability depends on what you expect the actual value of the bytes to be. It's unclear.